# Reloading 'sub' pages with Webpack dev server not working

Tags: webpack, react-router, webpack-2

I am migrating a project from Gulp to Webpack 2. This is a client-server app (using express). I had to include the webpack middlewares in my server, and also added this bit:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.normalize(`${__dirname}/../client/index.html`));
});
```

Now, the problem with this is, that now if click about in the application, things work fine, react router loads the sub pages, so all ok. However if I try to reload any of those sub pages (like localhost:3000/account, etc. I'll get a blank page). I think this is because for '*' the index.html is served up, which won't render in this situation (not sure why, but I can see the source of the page that is being shown and it's the index.html). I tried to include the historyApiFallback in the dev server config, but didn't help).

Comment: It seems like it's not entirely the same index.html, in the reload-scenario the script bit is missing, so that's the explanation why I am getting a blank page. Now I only need to figure out why the script tag is omitted...

Answer (score 0):

So I realised that the problem was that the devserver was returning the raw html file as opposed to the one that got compiled by Webpack. With this in hand I did another googling and found a better way to set up the devserver:

```
app.use('*', function (req, res, next) {
  var filename = path.join(compiler.outputPath,'index.html');
  compiler.outputFileSystem.readFile(filename, function(err, result){
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.set('content-type','text/html');
    res.send(result);
    res.end();
  });
});
```

(See here: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/145)